# regexpression allowing semicolon through

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to filter out anything other than letters, numbers, space,(,),/,-,and a ..
This is the code I am using.  It does some filtering but allows quotes, semicolons, and a few other things through.  Where did I go wrong?

```
filteredst = Regex.Replace(st, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9 .()/-]+", String.Empty);
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the negation operator inside of your class instead of applying it as the beginning of string anchor.

```
Regex.Replace(st, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9 .()/-]+", String.Empty);
```

Example:

```
String s = @"foo/bar ''''(baz.) """"12-34;:;;!%$@";
String r = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9 .()/-]+", String.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(r); //=> "foo/bar (baz.) 12-34"
```